# Which cgroup version(s) does Linux use by default?

Tags: linux, mount, cgroup

By default does Linux always initially mount both cgroupv1 and cgroupv2? What determines whether a Linux machine initially decides to use just cgroupv1 or just cgroupv2 or both?

Thanks in advance,

James Pedersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph here seems to provide an answer:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/NEWS#L1365

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).